# Limit video preview to 5 mins or 10 MB size in Documents & Media portlet

Tags: video, liferay, liferay-6, preview

Is there a configuration to limit the video preview to 5 mins or to a particular file size say 10 MB of preview.

I have set-up Xuggler, ImageMagick and the video preview is working fine on Liferay 6.1 GA2.

The reason I need this is because large files are taking a lot of time for preview generation and this is affecting other previews to be generated since the xuggler queue waits till the time the big preview is completed.

I have got this link to [FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) from the [Preview generation wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Preview+Generation#section-Preview+Generation-Advanced+Configuration) which lists some options to do this, but I am not sure how to use this or how to set this in `portal-ext.properties` or is this possible at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a full documentation, but as you seem desperate and nobody answered yet:

The properties end up in a call to xuggler's [`Configuration.configure(Properties properties, IConfigurable config)`](http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/Configuration.html#configure%28java.util.Properties,%20com.xuggle.xuggler.IConfigurable%29), stripped of the prefix `xuggler.ffpreset.`

I'm sorry, I can't currently try. The big problem that I'll leave for you is how to know the actual properties names. I'd try either the ones that you link in your question or get some more names/ideas/links from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868911). Try

```
# assuming decimal 10M limit
xuggler.ffpreset.fs 10000000
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf for the hint in this direction. Will see what works.